# Как сделать сложную фигуру с помощью CSS?

Tags: css, svg, форма

Возможно ли создать такую форму используя только CSS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно, clip-path: polygon(). вопрос в уровне детализации.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Border-radius_generator Если вы согласны на компромисный вариант.

Comment: @Poz Выберите ответ, который вам подошёл и отметьте его галочкой (слева от цифры ответа и нажмите upvote - верхний серый треугольник)

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 4):

*Для полного комплекта, - решение SVG*

Контур фигуры рисуете в векторном редакторе.

При наведении курсора - изменение цвета

После клика переход по ссылке на раздел вопросов по CSS

```css
.container {
width:20vw;
height:auto;
}
.path {
fill:#D12036;
}
.path:hover {
fill:yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  id="svg4" viewBox="0 0 180 65">
  
  <path class="path" d="M163.7 50.7c-13 6.2-28 6.6-42.3 8.7-13.3 2-26.8 2.8-40.2 3.7-10.6.8-19.9 1.4-31 .7-18.8-.7-53.6-15-47.9-37.4A30.5 30.5 0 0 1 18 8.4a49.3 49.3 0 0 1 34-6.3C57 3 62 5 67 6 73.3 7 79.7 8 86.2 8c14.8-.7 28.6-3.5 42.3-4.4 7.2-.5 14.6-1 21.7 0 10.1 1.3 21.2 3.8 26.2 12.6a26.4 26.4 0 0 1 2.2 16.8c-3 7-8.4 14.4-15 17.6z"  />
</svg>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) для этой задачи.

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 177px;
  height: 63px;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-mask: url('//i.imgur.com/QlE7nWV.png') no-repeat center center / contain;
          mask: url('//i.imgur.com/QlE7nWV.png') no-repeat center center / contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

НО.
• Это всё так же картинка, но можно использовать SVG, чтобы не было лесенок если этот блок будет менять размеры
• У блока таргет зона будет как у "прямоугольного блока", а не по форме фигуры.
• Стоит обратить внимание на поддержку - [ссылка](https://caniuse.com/css-masks)